# CNN classifier on dataset with one random class

Tags: keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a CNN classifier using keras to classify if the image is monkey or not. So I have two categories. One with monkey pictures. The other category is a random collection of pictures which is basically any picture that doesn't contain a monkey in it. Is appropriate to have a dataset with one class that is random and the other class with a specific label (rather than having 2 specific classes like cats and dogs)? will a CNN work for this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes .. CNN will work either you have one label set or many . If you need more details refer this link. This will save your day ..

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/12/11/image-classification-with-keras-and-deep-learning/

Comment: glad it helped you..!

Comment: Good answer! Try to limit the "not monkey" class as much as you can. If you know the input is an animal, use only animals other than monkeys for the other class. This will improve accuracy because irrelevant information is not learned by the model while focusing on differences between animals. I have some ready to go code online for "Hotdog or not a Hotdog" see [here](https://github.com/pietz/NDLS2017-CognitiveAI/blob/master/NDLS%202017%20-%20Coding%20Examples.ipynb). Also, I'd recommend using [ImageNet](http://image-net.org) to get the images instead of Google.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you think imagenet is better for this application?

Comment: Imagenet is a world  **organised** image database where many people organized and uploaded the image database with correct labels . downloading from imagenet with correct label will increase your model to learn quickly , instead of downloading unorganised image repositories.